# Как переключиться на новый репозиторий github

Tags: github

Создал новый репозиторий, нужно переключиться со старого на новый, как это можно сделать? Создавать новую папку и в ней писать git init? А потом клонировать например?

Comment: Как именно создал? И что означает "переключиться"?

Comment: Создал на гитхабе новый репозиторий, как в локальном репозитории переключится на новый репозиторий, который только что создал

Comment: Уточню: у вас есть проект с файлами итд. И вы сейчас хотите зачем-то переключить удаленный репозиторий этого проекта на совсем другой, пустой репозиторий? Так?

Comment: Нет, я создал новый репозиторий для написания нового проекта. Но локальный репозиторий находится на старом удлаенном репозитории, а нужно переключится на новый, чтобы начать новый проект

Comment: Вам нужен `git remote add origin <new_repo.git>`, видимо

Comment: Тогда да, создать папку и потом клонировать. Только это не "переключиться", потому что ничего никуда не переключается.

Answer (score -1):

В GitHub Descktop переключаются между репозиториями как на картинке ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]